# Regular Expression For This Scenario

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let's say this is the text we're dealing with

```
blah

blah

blah

StartAwesomeEnd

blah
```

How do we select everything before "Start"? not just the current line but everything before Start?

Also how do we select everything after "End"?
Thanks for helping, I'm new to regular expressions

Comment: Do you need to match anything before the *first* or *last* `Start`? The first/last `Start` at the *beginning of the line* or anywhere in the file? Is the `Start` a part of a word, or it does not matter?

Comment: Please add clarifications to the question itself by editing it. Also, what `End` do you mean? One that comes after `Start` or any `End` in the file (see the questions about `Start` above).

Comment: but I added quotations for it to be easy to understand :(

Comment: `(?s).*Start` and `(?s)End.*`?

Comment: By the way, nobody said your question is hard to understand. Wiktor just asked for more details. To construct a good regex, you need to know exactly what it's supposed to do. You'd do well to answer people's questions, even if the answer is "it doesn't matter".

Comment: extremely sorry I didn't read Wiktor's first comment, my eyes missed it, Rawing your regular expressions are omitting this error "invalid target for quantifier"

Comment: Sorry, we can't help without more details, and surely it is even harder without the explanation what you have done, and how/why those attempts failed. SO is not a free code writing service, we help to solve issues with users' code/patterns. Sometimes, we do share solutions when no attempts posted, but in those cases, the questions must be crystal clear and show involvement from the OP side.

Answer (score 0):

`^([\W\w]*?)Start[\W\w]*?End([\W\w]*?)$`

It's a little processing intensive, but should do the trick. This regex features:

- Grouping everything before the first "Start"
- Skipping over "Start" + any text up to the next "End" + "End"
- Grouping everything after that.

Not sure if that's what you needed, but this should help steer you in a useful direction.